# FULLTEXT search NOT working on two columns

Tags: mysql, node.js

**Background:**

Hey I'm using `MySQL 5.6.17 InnoDB`, I've read on mysql website that FULLTEXT is now avaiable for InnoDB in 5.6+ version. so i don't have to change from InnoDB to MyISAM [Here is the link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) I altered TWO of my table columns for FULLTEXT search by using the following query

```
ALTER TABLE `es_officers` ADD FULLTEXT Index_officer_name (es_officer_name)
ALTER TABLE `es_officers` ADD FULLTEXT Index_officer_fname (es_officer_fname)
```

**Altered Table Registered in Information Schema:**

Then i checked in my information schema if the altered table columns are registered or not by running the following query

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM statistics
WHERE index_type LIKE 'FULLTEXT%'
```

It showed me exacttly two results which i was expecting

[image: Information Schema results]

**Problem:**

when i write a query to MATCH a sting AGAINST two columns it gives me an error

```
SELECT * FROM `es_officers` WHERE MATCH (es_officer_name, es_officer_fname) AGAINST ('abc')

#1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

**BUT:**

when i try to query the columns separately like below it works absolutely fine

```
SELECT * FROM `es_officers` WHERE MATCH (es_officer_name) AGAINST ('abc')

SELECT * FROM `es_officers` WHERE MATCH (es_officer_fname) AGAINST ('abc')
```

I don't know what is it I'm doing wrong, help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiples issues:

You have two separate fulltext indexes, each covering a single field. You have `WHERE MATCH (es_officer_name, es_officer_fname)` as your query, which requires a **SINGLE** index covering both fields. MySQL will not use two separate indexes for this query - it can't. that's not how fulltext indexing works. You need an `alter ... fulltext (es_officer_name, es_officer_fname)` instead added.

And even then, `abc` will fall under the default [minimum word length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) and won't get indexed.

Comment: OK, so If i do ALTER TABLE `es_officers` ADD FULLTEXT Index (es_officer_name, es_officer_fname) and if the minimum word length is 4 which is default for mysql fulltext, this should work right ? also i've to ask you few more things

Comment: 1: I was trying to avoid the following query because I've around 20 columns in one table and I had to match the string through every column but in case of FULLTEXT my minimum word length is 4 and if I'm giving it 2 it won't work.

SELECT * FROM `es_officers` WHERE es_officer_name LIKE '%abc%' OR es_officer_fname LIKE '%abc%' OR es_officer_EDFA LIKE '%abc%' 

I have to write this "LIKE '%abc'" part 20 times, is there a way to avoid it ??

Comment: you can change the min length. it's configurable. you just have to rebuild the indexes after changing the length limits. and since `like %...%` queries can't use indexes anyways, you can hack a simpler version like `concat(field1,field2,etc...) LIKE '%abc%'`.

Comment: ok really appreciate your help, I just tried this concat and it worked like a charm, can you please tell me 1: which method is faster and better in your opinion, the FULLTEXT or the general one LIKE '%abc%' 2: please guide me how to configure this minimum length word

Comment: fulltext by far, since it's an index. the `like` version has to pull the records off disk, glue them all together, then do a string search for `abc`, which is massively inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Besides, you can try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM es_officers
WHERE MATCH es_officer_name AGAINST ('abc') + MATCH es_officer_fname AGAINST ('abc')
```

Though, as [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) said, 'abc' value is too short.

Comment: Thanks I jumped to FULLTEXT because I was trying to avoid repeating the string part or MATCH () AGAINST () part, for LIKE part @Marc B told me to use concat and it works find, but for full text part i've to alter my alter table query.